# How can I get unmanaged object from Realm query in Swift?

Tags: swift, cocoa, realm

In Java, you can get unmanaged objects with this:

```
Realm realm = Realm.getDefaultInstance();
realm.beginTransaction();
dogs = realm.where(Dog.class).lessThan("age", 2).findAll()
realm.commitTransaction();
realm.close()
```

How can I do this in Swift with Realm-cocoa ?

Answer (score 7):

To get an unmanaged object from Realm in Swift you can use `init(value: AnyObject)` initializer:

```
let unmanagedObject = Object(value: existingObject)
```

BTW in your code sample you don't get an unmanaged object as well, you need to use something like this in Java:

```
RealmObject unmanagedObject = Realm.copyFromRealm(RealmObject existingObject)
```

See more in [docs](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/#what-is-the-difference-between-a-normal-java-object-and-a-realm-object).

Comment: when i do this any fields in the copied realm object that were also realm objects do not get copied -- they remain managed realm objects. is that expected behavior?

Comment: cannot find this method in ObjectiveC :/

Comment: for objective-c look at git, for an extension, deepCopy
https://github.com/yusuga/RLMObject-Copying

this an old code - i have a fix, for the function.

Answer (score 1):

for objective c there are helper classes.
https://github.com/yusuga/RLMObject-Copying

very old and outdated - an important fix would be

```
- (instancetype)deepCopy {
    Class objClass = [RLMSchema classForString:self.objectSchema.className];
    RLMObject *object = [[objClass alloc] init];

    for (RLMProperty *property in self.objectSchema.properties) {

        if (property.array) {
            RLMArray *thisArray = [self valueForKeyPath:property.name];
            RLMArray *newArray = [object valueForKeyPath:property.name];

            for (RLMObject *currentObject in thisArray) {
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NSString class]]) {
                    [newArray addObject:(NSString*)[currentObject copy]];
                }else if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NSNumber class]]) {
                    [newArray addObject:(NSNumber*)[currentObject copy]];
                }else if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NSDate class]]) {
                    [newArray addObject:(NSDate*)[currentObject copy]];
                }else if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[NSData class]]) {
                    [newArray addObject:(NSData*)[currentObject copy]];
                }else {
                     [newArray addObject:[currentObject deepCopy]];
                }
            }

        }
        else if (property.type == RLMPropertyTypeObject) {
            RLMObject *value = [self valueForKeyPath:property.name];
            [object setValue:[value deepCopy] forKeyPath:property.name];
        }
        else {
            id value = [self valueForKeyPath:property.name];
            [object setValue:value forKeyPath:property.name];
        }
    }

    return object;
}
```