# How to get an unmanaged version of a Realm Object

Tags: ios, realm

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39040081/6744473), all that's necessary to get an unmanaged object from an existing managed object is to do this:

```
let unmanagedObject = Object(value: existingObject)
```

However, when I do this, any fields of the `existingObject` that are managed realm objects themselves remain managed realm objects after copying. What do I have to do so that all sub-objects of the copy also become unmanaged?

Comment: hey, were you able to resolve this? I need to do the same

Comment: @waheeda Yea, I ended up creating a `copy()` function on the object, and inside of it I created a new object, initialized all the fields manually, and then returned it